# PHP - How to Fill Cell with color from FPDF Function

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a table generated pdf via fpdf and I needed something that will auto-wrap my cells if I need so I stumbled upon this: https://github.com/gemul/fpdf-multicell-table/blob/master/pdf_mc_table.php

With that, I have the following command for my page header:

```
function Header(){
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $this->Cell(100,10,'Otaku Loaning Org', 0 , 1);
    $this->Ln(5);

    $this->SetWidths(Array(21,30,15,15,27,31,31,));
    $this->SetLineHeight(5);
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this->SetFillColor(180,180,255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(50,50,100);
    $this->Row(Array(
            'Date',
            'Name',
            'Trans ID',
            'Loan ID',
            'Interest Charge',
            'Amount Paid',
            'Total'

    ));

}
```

It currently looks like this:[image: looks]

However, as you can see I prepared a line of code for the Cells to be filled with a color. I would appreciate if someone could provide some insights because I tried adding a seventh parameter to line 60 and set it as true but to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: Your draw color line `SetDrawColor(50,50,100);` also appears to be having no effect. Are you viewing the pdf in the browser or via a pdf viewer, or some other way? I ask because it could be an issue of a "print view" for the pdf, where it's showing all in monochrome.

Comment: I am using the pdf viewer extension for opera gx to view changes that I make

Comment: Line 58 is the one to change: `$this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h,'DF');`.